# What is the purpose of the characteristic exponent?

Tags: terminology, field-theory

I just came across the term "*characteristic exponent*" of a field $\Bbbk$. Apparently, it is equal to $1$ if $\DeclareMathOperator{\c}{char}\c(\Bbbk)=0$ and it is equal to $p=\c(\Bbbk)$ otherwise. Going to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_exponent_of_a_field) was extremely unhelpful as you can see when searching for the term "*characteristic exponent*" on the page it redirects you to.

Comment: Did you find the term only on wikipedia or also somewhere else? I would bet that it is related to the last possible meaning on the disambiguity page: "An exponent of a power series with non-negative coefficient, that is not divisible by the highest common factor of preceding exponents with non-zero coefficients."

Comment: No, it's from a paper, it is about fields and it is defined there exactly the way I defined it.

Comment: On first glance, it looks like a convenient way to shorten hypotheses: http://books.google.ca/books?id=bDLecF34d8UC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=field+characteristic+exponent&source=bl&ots=b_uV5JqeDb&sig=Vqcqov3ARy9j3n4aL1zNsjOF52k&hl=en#v=onepage&q=field%20characteristic%20exponent&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simplifies some statements of theorems and properties. For instance one could define

> A field $K$ of characteristic exponent $p$ is perfect, if $K^p = K$.

Or, suppose you have a field $K$ of characteristic exponent $p$ and you want to study its connection to $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ or to some $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$-module. It would be tedious to consider $\mbox{char}(K)=0$ seperately.